# SharePoint 2010 Wiki Template Script Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for a way to give my SharePoint users a way to create new wiki pages from an existing template.  In the process of researching I found a great walkthrough that seems to fit the need (http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1072&page=2), but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  The problem seems to lie in the assignment of a path to PATHTOWIKI-- if I use "/Weekly Update Wiki", the script returns an error of "There is no Web named '/Weekly Update Wiki'."  If I use "Weekly Update Wiki" without the forward slash, I instead get an error of "There is no Web named '/sites/[parentSite]/[childSite]/Weekly Update Wiki/Weekly Update Wiki'."

Any ideas about what I'm not understanding here?

```
function myCreateProject() {
    // Configure these for your environment
    // include no slashes in paths
    var PATHTOWIKI = "Weekly Update Wiki";
    var PATHTOPAGES = "Pages";
    // file name only for template page, no extension
    var TEMPLATEFILENAME = "Template";

    var myPathToWiki = encodeURIComponent(PATHTOWIKI);
    var myPathToPages = PATHTOPAGES + "%2f";
    var myTemplateFileName = encodeURIComponent(TEMPLATEFILENAME) + "%2easpx";

    var EnteredProject = document.getElementById("NewProjName");
    var myNewName = EnteredProject.value;

    if(myNewName == "") {
        alert('Please enter a name for the new project page'); 
    } else {
        myNewName = encodeURIComponent(myNewName) + "%2easpx"
        $.ajax({
            url: PATHTOWIKI + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll",
            data: ( "method=move+document%3a14%2e0%2e0%2e4730&service%5fname="
                + myPathToWiki +
                "&oldUrl=" + myPathToPages + myTemplateFileName +
                "&newUrl=" + myPathToPages + myNewName +
                "&url%5flist=%5b%5d&rename%5foption=nochangeall&put%5foption=edit&docopy=true"
            ),
            success: function(data) {
                var rpcmsg1 = getMessage(data, "message=", "<p>");
                $("#myInfo").append("<br />" + rpcmsg1);
                if(rpcmsg1.indexOf("successfully") < 0) {
                    // get error info
                    var rpcmsg2 = getMessage(data, "msg=", "<li>");
                    $("#myInfo").append("<br />" + rpcmsg2 + "<br />");
                } else {
                    $("#myInfo").append("<br /><a href=\"/" + PATHTOWIKI + "/" + PATHTOPAGES + "/" + myNewName + "\">Go to new page</a><br />");
                }
            },
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Vermeer-Content-Type", 
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Update: I figured out what needed to happen in my case.  Since I couldn't get a grasp on the relative approach, I just went with the absolute path for PATHTOWIKI and slightly modified the append in the ajax call.

PATHTOWIKI:

```
var PATHTOWIKI = "https://[domain]/sites/[parentSite]/[childSite]";
```

append:

```
$("#myInfo").append("<br /><a href=\"" + PATHTOWIKI + "/" + PATHTOPAGES + "/" + myNewName + "\">Go to new page</a><br />");
```

The change in the latter line of code is subtle; since I used an absolute path in PATHTOWIKI, I just removed the leading forward slash in the anchor tag, so that `<a href=\"/"` became `<a href=\""`.  This renders the script slightly less portable, but since it's a one-off effort I'll stick with this unless anything comes along to expand the scope.

Comment: Is PATHTOWIKI a web site? Or document library?

Comment: That's a good question.  I actually just figured this out and will post the revision in the original post.